# Rowcolor for tabu

Tags: tabu, colortbl

Rowcolor need to update from top row to bottom row, in tabu package
row colors updating bottom to top row, how to apply color changes as default in top  to bottom row color as alternative.

Note: When I use `\taburowcolors[1]{rowcolor..white}` which was changed rowcolor color value percentages in PDF output.

Please find MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %for use in color links
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\makeatletter

\def\tstrut{}
\def\bstrut{}

\definecolor{rowcolor}{cmyk}{0.11,0.08,0.07,0}

\long\def\tabuprocesstable#1#2#3{\bgroup%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TEMP%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\arrayrulewidth=1pt
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TEMP%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\rowcolors{1}{rowcolor}{white}
\def\arraystretch{1.7}%
\parindent0pt
#1\par%
\noindent{#2}\par%
{#3}\par%
\egroup}%

\def\colhead#1{\sffamily\bfseries#1}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[!h]\tabuprocesstable{}
{\begin{tabu}{L{230pt}L{140pt}}

\colhead{\textbf{Subject}}
&
\colhead{\textbf{Paragraphs}}
\\
Selection and application of accounting policies
&
7–12
\\
Consistency of accounting policies
&
13
\\
Changes in accounting policies
&
14–27
\\
Disclosure of changes in accounting policies
&
28–31
\\
Changes in accounting estimates
&
32–40
\\
Errors
&
41–42
\\
XX&YY\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}
{}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]\tabuprocesstable{}
{\begin{tabu}{L{230pt}L{140pt}}

\colhead{\textbf{Subject}}
&
\colhead{\textbf{Paragraphs}}
\\
Selection and application of accounting policies
&
7–12
\\
Consistency of accounting policies
&
13
\\
Changes in accounting policies
&
14–27
\\
Disclosure of changes in accounting policies
&
28–31
\\
Changes in accounting estimates
&
32–40
\\
Errors
&
41–42
\\
\tabucline{-}
\end{tabu}}
{}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you don't seem to use `tabu`'s `X` type columns at all, why not switch to a simple `tabular` (or `longtable` if you need pagebreaks inside of the table)?

Comment: The `tabu` package is buggy and not maintained. Consider to switch to some other package, as suggested @leandriis in his comment. Use `[table]{xcolor}` for your desired result is far more reliable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't seem to use `tabu`'s `X` type columns, there is not really a need for `tabu` at all. You can use a simple `tabular` instead. In the following example I have also used the `\rowcolors` command in order to achieve alternating row colors.

Since your table is too wide for the textwidth of a standard `book` page (see red lines), you might want to reduce the overall width of the table. This can either be done using `l` type columns instead of fixed width `L` type columns. The contents of your table are short enough that the table will fit into the textwidth without the need for linebreaks in the cells contents. Alternatively, and especially if you will add wider contents in the first column, you might want to have a look at the `tabularx` package (see 3rd example):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} %for use in color links
%\usepackage{colortbl} % Not needed as automatically loaded by \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}


%%%%% Show border of textblock. Do not use in real document
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tabularx} % Only used for third example

\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
%\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\definecolor{rowcolor}{cmyk}{0.11,0.08,0.07,0}
\newcommand{\colhead}[1]{\sffamily\textbf{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
\rowcolors{1}{rowcolor}{white}
\begin{tabular}{L{230pt}L{140pt}}
\colhead{Subject}
&
\colhead{Paragraphs}
\\
Selection and application of accounting policies
&
7–12
\\
Consistency of accounting policies
&
13
\\
Changes in accounting policies
&
14–27
\\
Disclosure of changes in accounting policies
&
28–31
\\
Changes in accounting estimates
&
32–40
\\
Errors
&
41–42
\\
XX&YY\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
\rowcolors{1}{rowcolor}{white}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\colhead{Subject}
&
\colhead{Paragraphs}
\\
Selection and application of accounting policies
&
7–12
\\
Consistency of accounting policies
&
13
\\
Changes in accounting policies
&
14–27
\\
Disclosure of changes in accounting policies
&
28–31
\\
Changes in accounting estimates
&
32–40
\\
Errors
&
41–42
\\
XX&YY\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[!h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.7}
\rowcolors{1}{rowcolor}{white}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
\colhead{Subject}
&
\colhead{Paragraphs}
\\
Selection and application of accounting policies
&
7–12
\\
Consistency of accounting policies
&
13
\\
Changes in accounting policies
&
14–27
\\
Disclosure of changes in accounting policies
&
28–31
\\
Changes in accounting estimates
&
32–40
\\
Errors
&
41–42
\\
XX&YY\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: In "tabular" alternative rowcolor output correct as what we expected, but we are using "tabu" for all tables using tools. We need an alternative rowcolor without color percentage changes using tabu.

Comment: @RajeshN: Could you please explain what you mean with "color percentage changes"?

Comment: @RajeshN: I'd usggest to not use the `tabu` package as it is currently unmaintained (See here: https://github.com/tabu-issues-for-future-maintainer/tabu)

Comment: I have given "rowcolor" CMYK value as: 0.11,0.08,0.07,0(given in preamble) which shows correct value in PDF output using "tabular", the color value changes in PDF output using "tabu" which shows color value as 0.10,0.04,0.05,0.

Comment: @RajeshN: I can't reproduce this. For me, the color is the same if I use `tabular` or `tabu`. Probably this is due to different package versions. However, I'd definitely recommend to not use `tabu` due to the package being currently unmaintained and due to various underired interactions that are possible.

Comment: @leandriis, good answer (+1). However, it seems that OP is lost in given options (which educative).